# How do I get a Nancy ISession instance within a SignalR Hub method called from the client?

Tags: c#, signalr, nancy

I have a [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) Hub that looks like this:

```
public class PatchHub : Hub
{
    ISession Session;
    public void RunPatch(string name)
    {
        PatchService.Run(Session, name);
    }
}
```

You can see that I need an instance of the current Nancy Session (`ISession`) whenever the `RunPatch(..)` method is called from the client via SignalR.

However my attempt to get Nancy to inject an instance by declaring `ISession Session;` as a class level variable has not worked.

Can you tell me how I can get an instance of the Nancy Session within a SignalR Hub class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PatchHub : Hub
{
    ISession _session;
    public PatchHub(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void RunPatch(string name)
    {
        PatchService.Run(_session, name);
    }
}
```

Btw, you may consider injecting `PatchService` as well, so you don't have hard dependency on it.